# State variable for Java Spring MVC Dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

We're using dependency injection in Java Spring MVC to add resources to controllers. For example:

```
@Autowired
public MyController(
    @Qualifier("MyOtherControllerA") MyOtherControllerA myOtherControllerA,                 
    @Qualifier("MyOtherControllerB") MyOtherControllerB myOtherControllerB)
{
    ...
}
```

We want to inject different dependencies for DEBUG mode and LIVE. For instance, for debug, we could have:

```
@Autowired
public MyController(
    @Qualifier("MyOtherControllerA_Mock") MyOtherControllerA myOtherControllerA,                 
    @Qualifier("MyOtherControllerB_Mock") MyOtherControllerB myOtherControllerB)
{
    ...
}
```

How do we do this?

Comment: Create a spring.xml configuration for live and a different spring.xml configuration for debug

Comment: With different beans? (and then don't use the annotations?) How do I tell Spring what config.xml to use?

Comment: might be worth taking a look at spring 3.2 andc its new testing features

Comment: If you put the spring config.xml on the classpath, you can easily switch between the live and debug versions by placing the desired config.xml on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the logic for different environments into your code.
Have a look at [environment specific configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284745/environment-specific-configuration-for-a-spring-based-web-application). They had a similar problem.